# Project schedule plot in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, scatter-plot

I want to make some changes in the plot done by my senior, in Java. And since I do not know that language, I want to do it in Matlab. I have attached both the data (text format) and plot here. It is the output of project schedule where the value represents the cost associated with task (link) and their continuation in time (say task 2 is done from 6th to 9th month and cost is 0.665m $).

Value 0 indicate that there is no work in that time period for a particular task (row). The plot in Java, shows the variation in time and cost for each task.

I have been trying to make similar kind of plot (bar in case of the circles) in Matlab but could not.

[image: java plot]

```
Link#   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.34    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   0   0   0   0   0   0.665   0.665   0.665   0.665   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3   0   0   0.34    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4   0.36    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
5   0.14    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
6   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.58    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
7   0   0   0   0.57    0.57    0.57    0.57    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
8   0.64    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
9   0.58    0.58    0.58    0.58    0.58    0.58    0.58    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
10  0.24    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
11  0.56    0.56    0.56    0.56    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
12  0.2 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
13  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.56    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
14  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.62    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
15  0   0   0   0.582857143 0.582857143 0.582857143 0.582857143 0.582857143 0.582857143 0.582857143 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
16  0.536   0.536   0.536   0.536   0.536   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
17  0.2 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
18  0   0.6 0.6 0.6 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
19  0   0   0   0   0.0000  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.606666667 0.606666667 0.606666667 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
20  0   0   0   0.633333333 0.633333333 0.633333333 0.633333333 0.633333333 0.633333333 0.633333333 0.633333333 0.633333333 0.633333333 0.633333333 0.633333333 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
21  0   0   0.606666667 0.606666667 0.606666667 0.606666667 0.606666667 0.606666667 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
22  0   0   0.643076923 0.643076923 0.643076923 0.643076923 0.643076923 0.643076923 0.643076923 0.643076923 0.643076923 0.643076923 0.643076923 0.643076923 0.643076923 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
23  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.58    0.58    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
24  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.651428571 0.651428571 0.651428571 0.651428571 0.651428571 0.651428571 0.651428571 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
25  0   0   0.62    0.62    0.62    0.62    0.62    0.62    0.62    0.62    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
26  0   0   0   0   0   0   0.62    0.62    0.62    0.62    0.62    0.62    0.62    0.62    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
27  0.546666667 0.546666667 0.546666667 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
28  0   0.655   0.655   0.655   0.655   0.655   0.655   0.655   0.655   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
29  0.5 0.5 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
30  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.44    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
31  0.54    0.54    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
32  0   0.64    0.64    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
33  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.611428571 0.611428571 0.611428571 0.611428571 0.611428571 0.611428571 0.611428571 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
34  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.62    0.62    0.62    0.62    0.62    0.62    0.62    0.62    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
35  0.36    0.36    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
36  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.65    0.65    0.65    0.65    0.65    0.65    0.65    0.65    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
37  0.38    0.38    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
38  0.613333333 0.613333333 0.613333333 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
39  0.58    0.58    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
40  0   0   0   0   0.647272727 0.647272727 0.647272727 0.647272727 0.647272727 0.647272727 0.647272727 0.647272727 0.647272727 0.647272727 0.647272727 0.647272727 0.647272727 0.647272727 0.647272727 0.647272727 0.647272727 0.647272727 0.647272727 0.647272727 0.647272727 0.647272727 0   0   0   0
```

[java plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjxWe.jpg)

Comment: So, what have you done in terms of code? Stack Overflow is not a service for writing your code. Please read up on [ask], as well as [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example for a solution, assuming `data` is all what is **within** the chart (i.e., no axis tick labels):

```
Links_num = size(data,1);
[y,x] = ndgrid(1:Links_num,1:size(data,2));
c = repelem(1:Links_num,size(data,2),1).';
scatter(x(:),y(:),data(:)*100+1,c(:),'filled')
clr = lines(Links_num);
colormap(clr)
title('Time Period')
ax = gca;
ax.XAxisLocation = 'top';
ax.XAxis.TickValues(1) = [];
clr = lines(Links_num); % make a color map
ax.YAxis.Direction = 'reverse';
links = [repmat('Link ',Links_num,1) num2str((1:Links_num).')];
x = repelem(ax.XAxis.Limits(1)-0.05,Links_num); % make an x position vector
for k = 1:Links_num
    text(ax.XAxis.Limits(1)-0.05,k,links(k,:),'Color',clr(k,:),...
        'HorizontalAlignment','right');
end
ax.YAxis.Visible = 'off'; % remove the original labels
```

The result:

[image: project schedule]

Comment: Works great! Can I replace the circle with continuous bar remaining all other things as it is (looks like horizontal bar chart)?

Comment: @santosh I thought that the circle size has a meaning, and so it is in this plot. How would you keep this information with a horizontal bar?

Comment: Just accepted answer. sorry for doing it late, new to this site. Yeah, size definitely has meaning. I was just wondering if I can present this information in any other format because my professor wants to modify this. Thanks!

Comment: @santosh well you can plot this in many formats, but you have to be very specific in what you ask. And also, another format is a subject for another question.

Comment: Can I use the bar in which color corresponds the value (lets say red corresponds to 0-0.2, blue 0.2-0.4,......) and we can fix the legend with information of that. The length of bar will indicate the time (x-axis).

Comment: or any format would be fine!

Comment: @santosh you can use [`barh`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/barh.html) for that, or choose any format that you like from [Matlab plotting functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/types-of-matlab-plots.html). Anyhow, this is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Could you please demonstrate an example with barh function, in this example. I am getting error using barh.

Comment: @santosh: perhaps you could give it a go first? You might have gotten someone to do your work for you once, but if you keep trying it, even the most generous of saints will ask you to help. What are you stuck on with your new requirement?